# iphone :- what is difference between activity indicator and network activity indicator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to know what is difference between activity indicator and network activity indicator ?

is this same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An activity indicator is a UIView that is a spinning icon to indicate loading/etc.  Since it is a view you can place it anywhere within your application.  The network activity indicator handles the animation on the device toolbar to indicate network activity.

Network Activity Indicator:
[image]

[UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)

Comment: Are you asking how to start and stop the Network Activity Indicator?  If so you can do(just swap out Yes/No to turn it on/off).. [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;